# Launching applications from GPIO button presses via a python script

Tags: gpio, python

I have a Python script that runs at startup and looks for GPIO inputs (*the buttons on my PiTFT screen*).  I can make the buttons do things like shut down the Pi (*`sudo shutdown now`*), but I'm stumped as to how to make the buttons launch applications like `lxterminal` or `pithos`. Here's what I have for the script - can anyone suggest why the button for shutdown works but the buttons for launching apps doesn't?  I have added a line in my `/etc/rc.local` that starts the script at startup via sudo, if that helps....

```
#!/bin/python
# a simple script for using the tactile buttons on the TFT

import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
import os

# Use Broadcom SOC Pin Numbers
# setup with internal pullups and pin in READ mode

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(23, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down = GPIO.PUD_UP)
GPIO.setup(22, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down = GPIO.PUD_UP)
GPIO.setup(27, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down = GPIO.PUD_UP)
GPIO.setup(18, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down = GPIO.PUD_UP)

#  Main Loop

while 1:
    if ( GPIO.input(22) == False ):
        os.system("sudo pithos")
        time.sleep(1)
    elif ( GPIO.input(27) == False ):
        os.system("sudo lxterminal --geometry=40x10")
        time.sleep(1)
    elif ( GPIO.input(18) == False ):
        os.system("sudo shutdown -h now")
        time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: Have you confirmed the code takes the paths by adding a print statement? By the way you should only use sudo when needed.

Comment: does it help if you add `sleep` before the python launch command. All my scripts in python use it. I think it should help

Answer (score 1):

You may use `subprocess.call()` function instad of `os.system` ([reference link](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html))

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call(["sudo", "lxterminal", "--geometry=40x10"])
```

Comment: I tried that and the apps still don't launch.  The Pi boots to the desktop, I punch the buttons, and still the only command that works is the one that does the shutdown.... :(

Answer (score 1):

This might be caused by some missing environment variables; namely the `DISPLAY` variable. It would explain why a command that doesn't use the display, e.g. `sudo shutdown -h now`, works while `sudo lxterminal --geometry=40x10` doesn't.

Assuming that your display is numbered 0 (default), try adding this at the top of your python script:

```
import os
os.putenv('DISPLAY', ':0')
```

It essentially tells the system where to send your `lxterminal` window in case you're not starting the process manually/from terminal. You can see the number of your display by typing `echo $DISPLAY` in terminal:

```
$ echo $DISPLAY
:0
```

Comment: Tried that - the PiTFT LCD display had a display value of :0.0 - and still nothing.  I think I need to figure out how to make my script write a logfile so that I can try to debug it that way....

Comment: @Wolfgang Yeah, that's always a good idea; so is using the `subprocess` module instead of `os.system` and writing out the full path to executables such as `lxterminal`; e.g. `import subprocess`, `subprocess.call(["/usr/bin/lxterminal", "--geometry=40x10"])`

Answer (score 1):

First of all, if you're running the script from `rc.local` you don't need to execute commands with `sudo` because they already are running with root privileges. It's redundant.

Have you confirmed that the commands you are attempting to execute are actually installed? Try running them manually from the command line.

A simple way to allow debugging is to simply insert print statements in your code:

```
print "debug: attempting to launch lxterminal"
```

They should show up in a system log, or you could redirect them to someplace specific by modifying the line that calls your script in `rc.local` like this:

```
/usr/local/bin/script.location.py >> /var/log/custom.script.log 2>&1
```

Maybe that will provide more information you can use to figure out what is going on.

Best of luck!

Comment: Any thoughts on [Why would os.system('sudo pigpiod') fail silently, but only part of the time?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/80271/35753)